# C++ 3-й массив минимального размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массивов 1 и 2, которые не являются общими для них. Ошибка на этапе выполнения

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-c++

Даны два массива: А[M] и B[N] (M и  N вводятся с клавиатуры). Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массивов A и B, которые не являются общими для них.

Мой код:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void sort(int *arrN, int sizeN)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeN; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sizeN; ++j)
        {
            if (arrN[j] < arrN[i])
            {
                tmp = arrN[j];
                arrN[j] = arrN[i];
                arrN[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));

    cout << "Даны два массива: А[M] и B[N] (M и  N вводятся с клавиатуры). Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массивов A и B, которые не являются общими для них\n\n";
{
            int sizeA, sizeB;
            cout << "Введите размер первого массива: ";
            cin >> sizeA;
            cout << "Введите размер второго массива: ";
            cin >> sizeB;
            int *arrA = new int[sizeA];
            int *arrB = new int[sizeB];
            cout << "\n\nПервый массив: ";
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
            {
                arrA[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
                cout << arrA[x] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n\nВторой массив: ";
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
            {
                arrB[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
                cout << arrB[x] << " ";
            }

            sort(arrA, sizeA);
            sort(arrB, sizeB);

            cout << "\n\nПервый массив (Отсортированный): ";
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
            {
                cout << arrA[x] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n\nВторой массив (Отсортированный): ";
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
            {
                cout << arrB[x] << " ";
            }

            int *arrC = new int[sizeA < sizeB ? sizeA : sizeB];
            int sizeC = 0;

            cout << endl << endl << endl;

            bool flag;
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
            {
                flag = true;
                for (int y = 0; y < sizeB; y++)
                {
                    if (arrA[x] == arrB[y])
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    arrC[sizeC] = arrA[x];
                    sizeC++;
                }
            }

            int y;
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
            {
                flag = true;
                for (y = 0; y < sizeB; y++)
                {
                    if (arrB[x] == arrA[y])
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    arrC[sizeC] = arrA[y];
                    sizeC++;
                }
            }
            sizeC--;

            cout << "\n\nТретий массив: ";
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeC; x++)
            {
                cout << arrC[x] << " ";
            }

            delete[] arrA;
            delete[] arrB;
            delete[] arrC;
}
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

В итоге получается пару правильных ответов и пару мусорных значений. 
Пример:

Первый массив: 7 6 6 2 1

Второй массив: 1 7 3 5 3

Первый массив (Отсортированный): 1 2 6 6 7

Второй массив (Отсортированный): 1 3 3 5 7

Третий массив: 2 6 6 -33686019 -33686019

---

Ошибка явно во фрагменте:

```
            int *arrC = new int[sizeA < sizeB ? sizeA : sizeB];
            int sizeC = 0;

            cout << endl << endl << endl;

            bool flag;
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
            {
                flag = true;
                for (int y = 0; y < sizeB; y++)
                {
                    if (arrA[x] == arrB[y])
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    arrC[sizeC] = arrA[x];
                    sizeC++;
                }
            }

            int y;
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
            {
                flag = true;
                for (y = 0; y < sizeB; y++)
                {
                    if (arrB[x] == arrA[y])
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    arrC[sizeC] = arrA[y];
                    sizeC++;
                }
            }
            sizeC--;
```

Но где конкретно и как исправить?

---

UPD 1.0

@Gin Tasan, после этих результатов появился звук и консоль залагала.

Первый массив: 4 1 8 1 7

Второй массив: 2 6 5 3

Первый массив (Отсортированный): 1 1 4 7 8

Второй массив (Отсортированный): 2 3 5 6

Третий массив: 1 1 2 3 4 5 6

Откомпилировал еще раз 10 и опять словил этот баг:

Первый массив: 8 3 1 7 6

Второй массив: 8 3 5 4 2

Первый массив (Отсортированный): 1 3 6 7 8

Второй массив (Отсортированный): 2 3 4 5 8

Третий массив: 1 2 4 5 6 7

---

UPD 1.2

@Эдуард Измалков, если я вас правильно понял, то код сейчас выглядит так:

```
    bool flag;
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
    {
        flag = true;
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeB; y++)
        {
            if (arrA[x] == arrB[y])
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == true)
        {
            arrC[sizeC] = arrA[x];
            sizeC++;
        }
    }
```

Все вроде бы работает, но есть 2 проблемы:

1) Если в одном массиве две одинаковых элемента а в другом аналогов этим элементам только 1 (либо 3-2. 4-3, неважно) то лишний элемент не появляется в третьем массиве. arrA{1,2,2}, arrB{2,4} -> Как есть: arrC{1,4}, как должно быть: arrC{1,2,4}

2) Через несколько проверочных компиляций произошла ошибка со звуком. Никакая надпись и ошибка не вывелась, только консоль залагала намертво и пришлось вырубать через Х. Результаты которые вывелись при той ошибке:

Первый массив: 3 5 7 2 6

Второй массив: 8 8 3 2 8

Первый массив (Отсортированный): 2 3 5 6 7

Второй массив (Отсортированный): 2 3 8 8 8

Третий массив: 5 6 7 8 8 8

Comment: Я так понимаю, в 3 массиве в итоге должно быть 2 6 6 3 3 5 ?

Comment: Абсолютно верно @Gin Tasan.

Comment: во втором цикле должно быть `x < sizeB` и `y < sizeA`. И далее `arrC[sizeC] = arrB[x]`. А так у Вас получается, что если `flag == true`, то `y` на этот момент указывает на область за последним элементом массива, т.е. на мусор. И размер `sizeC` маловат, если массивы не совпадают вообще, то места не хватит.

Comment: еще `sizeC--` лишний, таким образом вы исключаете из вывода последний элемент.

Comment: Я вам ответил в самом вопросе в конце. Пожалуйста обратите внимание. @Эдуард Измалков

Comment: Вам еще нужно знать какие ошибки были в вашем коде ?

Comment: В принципе уже не нужно, я проанализировал ваш код и понял его суть. Не вижу смысла анализировать устаревший код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите , могу отписать , какие ошибки в вашем варианте

UPD: Сделайте размер массива #3 как sizeA + sizeB, что бы не вылетел тот самый баг

```js
  for (int x = 0, y = 0; x <sizeA && y < sizeB; )
{
 if (arrA[x] > arrB[y]) { 
  arrC[sizeC++] = arrB[y++]; if (y == sizeB && arrA[x]!=NULL) while (x < sizeA)  arrC[sizeC++] = arrA[x++]; 
  
 }
 
 else if (arrA[x] < arrB[y]) { 
  arrC[sizeC++] = arrA[x++]; if (x == sizeA && arrB[y] != NULL) while (y < sizeB)  arrC[sizeC++] = arrB[y++];
  
 }
 
 else    if (arrA[x] == arrB[y]) {
  x++; y++; 


  if (y == sizeB && arrA[x]) { while (x < sizeA) { arrC[sizeC++] = arrA[x++]; } }
  if (x == sizeA && arrB[y]) { while (y < sizeB) { arrC[sizeC++] = arrB[y++]; } }

  if (y == sizeB && arrA[x - 1] == arrA[x]) { arrC[sizeC++] = arrA[x]; }; if (x == sizeA && arrB[y - 1] == arrB[y]) { arrC[sizeC++] = arrB[y]; }
 }

}
```

Comment: Было бы супер :)) Спасибо заранее. Кстати, у вас последняя 9-ка не вывелась? Просто в первом массиве две 9-ки, а во-втором только одна. Получается одна лишняя и должна бы вывестись?

Comment: @HikoMoff, Не вывелась, специально так сделал, ибо девятка существует и в том и в том массиве, а нужно что бы вывелась?

Comment: проверил ваш алгоритм, в некоторых случаях появляется так сказать баг. При нажатии enter в консоли, чтобы выйти из него звук и консоль залагивает и завершается только выходом с помощью кнопки X. Кстати, да, ведь если было бы arrA{9,9} а arrB{9} то должна вывестись одна arrC{9} ведь она не относится к той 9-ке которая выбыла от соответствующей к ней аналогичной 9-ке в другом массиве.

Comment: @HikoMoff , в каких именно ?

Comment: так как числа генерируются рандомно, бывает раз в 2-3 компиляции такой баг

Comment: @HikoMoff, на счет бага посмотрю, но у меня также рандомно генерируются числа и я проверял совершенно разные случаи, такого ни разу не наблюдал, а код сейчас переделаю, 2 мин

Comment: сейчас отправлю в своем вопросе то, что появилось до бага в консоли. В комментариях код нечитабельно отправляется.

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё работает. Прошу прощение за спам, я просто хотел бы спросить. Тут можно как-то код отформатированный отправлять именно в этих комментариях или же тут так и надо в своем вопросе под заголовком каждый раз дополнять редактируя и указывать ник человека которому обращаешься?

Comment: @HikoMoff , тут еще чат есть, в котором продолжается общение, если в комментариях слишком уж большая беседа, однако, ни в чате , ни в комментариях нельзя отправлять отформатированный код, они служать только для каких либо уточнений. В основном, да , только обновлять вопрос с подписью UPD(1,2... и тд):

Comment: У вашего кода проблема с 9-ми.  Она их просто не видит. Не знаю с чем может быть связано.  //  Первый массив (Отсортированный): 4 5 9 9 9 // Второй массив (Отсортированный): 1 2 5 5 6 // Третий массив: 1 2 4 5 6. У вас 9-ки отображаются в итоге?

Comment: @HikoMoff, все исправил

Comment: а из-за чего это было? @Gin Tasan

Comment: @HikoMoff , из за того, что после сравнения - if (arrA[x] > arrB[y]) была только запись, когда итерация была на элементе 9 и сравнивала его с 5 , а потом с 6 , после сравнения с 6 переменная y была равна sizeB , поэтому цикл просто завершался, я добавил проверку на y == sizeB и проверку на NULL того элемента, который в другом массиве, и если он не NULL, что вполне так и может быть,ост. элементы просто записываются дальше по порядку в массив

Answer (score 0):

для этих целей существует `set`
http://cppstudio.com/post/9037/

Comment: Мы это еще не проходили. Приходится довольствоваться тем, что есть. Максимум это указатели :) Мне просто нужно исправить свой код. Я не могу найти ошибку. @alch